# Print values form an stdObject inside an Array from JSON Response

Tags: php, json, object, echo, valuestack

Im kinda new with php and JSON, and after digging around for a response I was not able to find one, I was hoping if you could help me…

I am working on a Report from with a JSON Response
The JSON response looks somewhat like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
[FlightInformation] => stdClass Object
    (
   [@size] => 10
     [Itinerary] => Array
       (
         [0] => stdClass Object
           (
            [bookingID] => 123456789
            [creationDate] => 10/04/2012
            [Customer] => stdClass Object
               (
                [email] => someone@aol.com
               )
               [FlightConfirmation] => stdClass Object
                  (
                    [supplierId] => AA
                    [arrivalDate] => 10/04/2012
                    [departureDate] => 10/05/2012
                    [confirmationNumber] => 0987654321
                    [RateInformation] => stdClass Object
                  (
                    [@size] => 1
                    [RateDescription] => stdClass Object
                        (
                         [@promo] => false
                         [ChargeableInfo] => stdClass Object
                             (
                              [@total] => 57.94
```

I building a Report that is like this..

```
foreach( $response->FlightInformation->Itinerary as $output) {

    echo $output-> bookingID;
    echo $output-> creationDate;
    echo $output-> arrivalDate;         <<<< won't Print
    echo $output->departureDate;    <<<< won't Print
    echo $output->total;            <<<< won't Print
```

and some more elements… but anything that is under an object inside de Itinerary Array won't show..
I cannot get to print thes values indicated, please help…

Cheers

Comment: Can you just add the raw JSON tooo

Comment: Try `$output->Customer->FlightConfirmation->arrivalDate`

Comment: Just to be clear, what you've got is a PHP object, that looks like it's representing a JSON response, which is slightly different than handing JSON directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because arrival, departure and total are objects themselves. You would have to do something like:

```
 $output->Customer->FlightConfirmation->arrivalDate;
 $output->Customer->FlightConfirmation->departureDate
 $output->Customer->FlightConfirmation->RateInformation->RateDescription->ChargeableInfo->total;
```

Comment: Thank you! it works! now I only have a problem which is, some how the Response comes with an @ on results... like total is @total... dont know what that is.

Comment: Hi, if you are getting that data from a web service or something that you can't control that just may be the way the data defined. Are you having an issue trying to access any of the values preceded with an @ symbol?

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a level of nesting those elements are inside `FlightConfirmation`: